# How to Serve a Local App Using Waitress and Nginx

Tags: python, nginx, windows-server-2008, plotly-dash, waitress

I have a dash(plotly) app set up using flask as the server and can serve it on our Windows Server to port:8041 using waitress. My code to launch waitress is below;

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from waitress import serve
from src.pacedash.app import server as application

if __name__ == "__main__":
    serve(application, threads=100, port=8041)
```

Everything works great if I use python run_waitress.py, except that when someone on our network navigates to the servename:8041 there is a "Not Secure" warning next to the url. Our IT vendor was able to get a cert file and key, but I'm not sure how to bring those into my current setup.

I have been trying to use nginx, but I can't find a guide to setting it up with waitress and I'm not too familiar with web apps or wsgi because I primarily work as the lone data person here.

Comment: Are you trying to add the ssl cert to nginx? http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html

Comment: Yes, but part of my more basic issue is just setting up nginx to talk to waitress. I really cannot seem to figure out how to get that working. I'd also accept a way to add the ssl cert without nginx, but I haven't seen anything suggesting I could do that.

Answer (score 2):

I'm absolutely solve problem of making work Waitress behind Nginx (HTTPs), not so easy, but in short:

If you use this command for start Waitress server from python code:

```
from waitress import serve

serve(app, listen='0.0.0.0:8080', url_scheme='https')
```

Using url_scheme='https' here, because in my case I need to allow HTTPs connection only, and for correct working between nginx and Waitress, we must use it

Common pattern:

1. if you don't have domain just use your server ip instead of your_domain (for get free certificates, you can use for example https://zerossl.com/),
2. instead of your_ip_address use your ip address that u connect, for example through ssh.

   ```
   server {
        listen 443 ssl;

        ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/fullchain.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/private.key;

        server_name your_domain www.your_domain;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://your_ip_address:8080;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        }
   }
   ```

NGINX requires all .crt files to be merged in order to allow SSL installation. so fullchain.crt is merged our certificate.crt and ca_bundle.crt files (UNIX terminal command):

```
cat certificate.crt ca_bundle.crt >> certificate.crt
```

If we have domain name example.com & get certificate through letsencrypt (certbot):

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;

    server_name example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://your_ip_address:8080;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }
}
```

This guide is help me, if something not clearly, ask me in comments or see this guide, where u can also find example of nginx config:
https://dev.to/thetrebelcc/how-to-run-a-flask-app-over-https-using-waitress-and-nginx-2020-235c

Answer (score 1):

I have been working on this same issue and have a solution. The nginx .conf file needs have a location defined like this:

```
location /myapp/ {
       # Define the location of the proxy server to send the request to
       proxy_pass http://localhost:8041/myapp/;

       # standard proxy_set_header stuff below...
}
```

Then in your Dash application set the url_base_pathname to the same value:

```
app = dash.Dash(__name__, url_base_pathname='/myapp/')
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use ngrok to expose your web app. It's amazingly simple:

Read this: https://ngrok.com/

I could be misinterpreting what you need, because I am not familiar with waitress (why not serve the app locally just using flask?), but if you need to test the live app, ngrok is what you should use.

Comment: I need to be able to share the web app to 40-50 other people at one time, it's a dashboard or relevant data and from what I've read I should be using the flask server to share it.